# What is happening behind the scenes for these basic Unix commands?

Tags: linux, shell

I was just playing with some basic Unix commands with following operations

1. create a file 'one'
2. create a link 'two' to 'one' (`ln one two`)
3. Edit the file 'one' and put words - one, two, three, four on separate lines.
4. Checked contents of 'two' - it has the same contents, so far so good.
5. Create a soft link 'three' to one. three also has same contents
6. Verified the number of links using `ls -l`.
7. Edited file 'one' and added word 'five' on a separate line.
8. Checked that files 'two' and 'three' have the same contents - so far so good
9. Edited soft link three (`vim three`) and added the word 'six' at the end.
10. Checked all the three files now have one to six in words.

Question - I understand if file 'one' gets contents of file 'three'. But why does file 'two' also get them?

If I do `ls -l`, I see that files one and two have 28 bytes, whereas file three has only 3 bytes (maybe for six). What is the reason for this?

Now if I remove file 'one', I see that three is still shown to be linked to one, but I cannot `cat three` and get error that file does not exist. But then why it is shown in the `ls` command?

Comment: Read up on symbolic links, which are just that - links. Hard links would be different. This is not about programming, so not really suitable for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does file 'two' also get them?

cause `ln(1)` make hard links by default, and 'two' is a hard link of 'one', according to the man page:

> A hard link to a file is indistinguishable from the original directory entry; any changes to a file are effectively independent of the name used to reference the file.

---

> If I do ls -l, I see that files one and two have 28 bytes, whereas file three has only 3 bytes (maybe for six). What is the reason for this?

cause the file content has 28 bytes, like this:

```
$ wc -c <<<'one two three four five six'
      28
```

except new line char replaced by space.

for the file 'three', it's a symbol link. a symbol link contains the name of the file to which it is linked. so 'three' would have size of the name of file 'one', and it's 3 bytes.

---

> Now if I remove file 'one', I see that three is still shown to be linked to one, but I cannot cat three and get error that file does not exist. But then why it is shown in the ls command?

If you remove file 'one', 'three' becomes a broken symbol link. Symbol links are a specific file type, unless you remove it explicitly, it would not disappear when the file it linked to is removed.

Comment: You may then ask, "why is there both 'hard-links' and 'symbolic-links'?" - One difference *I think* is that hard-links, because they refer to the *same* physical location (i-node) have to be on the same *physical* file-system(partition) however symbol-links being just file-names (either relative OR absolute) can point to a file on a *different* file-system.  Of course such "cross-dev" links can make the work of utilities such as 'find' harder (symbolic-links can be circular e.g. if "fileA" is a symlink to "fileB" and "fileB" is one to "fileA") - which is avoided by certain option arguments...